# EntityFramework - One to one relationship with Artist model

Tags: entity-framework, data-modeling

So i have two models: Artist and Album.

Artist:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Album:

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Review> Review { get; set; }
}
```

Each artist can have multiple albums. 
I want each artist to be tied to a single user identity.

I am using Individual Accounts authentication for my project, so I bascially want to set up a one-to-one relationship between Artist and the User Identity that is already set up by choosing Individual Accounts.

Also, is there a better way to do this? All I want is for each authenticated user to be able to have multiple albums.

**UPDATE**
Using a code first approach with Entity Framework.

Comment: The only question I see here is "Is there a better way to do this?" which is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes entity framework @haim770

Comment: Do you use code first ?

Comment: Yes code first @hasan

Comment: in my opinion you dont need to artist class if any user dont have multiple artist id, you can make one to one relation between Album and AspNetUsers by creating new class UserAlbums

Comment: so in this case classes are AspnetUsers, Album, UserAlbums

Comment: Better way? Probably not. Contrary to what many people do, it's a good idea to leave the ASP.Net authentication model alone and only *associate* to it.

Comment: @GertArnold would it be better to use AspnetUsers, Artist, Album, ArtistAlbums by associating Users with Artist with UserId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create relationship between AspnetUsers and Artist model by using `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` DataAnnotation attribute. And I think you need to one to many relationship between Artist and Album model classes because any artist can have multiple album in this case. You can use following code and add migration.

**Album Model :**

```
public class Album
{
    public Album(){

    }

    public int AlbumID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Review> Review { get; set; }

}
```

**Artist Model:**

```
public class Artist
{
    public Artist() 
    {
        this.Albums = new HashSet<Album>();
    }

    public int ArtistID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }

}
```

**ModelBuilder Part:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
                    .HasRequired<Artist>(s => s.Artist) // Album entity requires Artist 
                    .WithMany(s => s.Artists); // Album entity includes many Artist entities

}
```

Comment: I dont think there should be a many-to-many relationship between Artist and Album since a single album can only have one artist but a single artist can have many albums. Otherwise this works. :D

Comment: Yes you are right relatively :) maybe they are music group then any album can have multiple artist :)

Comment: True, but with my current idea it is not needed. But this is useful for anyone else who is trying to set up a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Also does this create a one-to-one relationship between Artist and AspnetUser? I single user should only be allowed to make a single artist. @hasan

Comment: I just associated Artist's UserId with AspNetUsers UserId by using [ForeignKey] Attribute and yes one user can be associated only one artist

Comment: Yes i saw. Thanks :)